# Using includes and stylesheets for a specific page?

Tags: php, html, css, include

I was about to use includes for my websites, setting up includes for
the header, footer, nav, etc. In the header I added the DOCTYPE to the end of the `</head>` tag.

If I do it this way, how would I add a stylesheet just for one specific page if the head of the page is in a include?

Comment: DOCTYPE needs to be placed before the <html> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there are alot of various ways to do this one would in the included header php file

add an variable

like so

```
<?=@$css;?>
```

and then in the file that includes it define the css variable to whatever you want to be included

```
$css = 'something';

include(header.php);
```

if this is your header.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?=@$css;?>
</head>
```

and this is your index.php

```
$css= '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
include('header.php');
```

Comment: Kinda lost, how would I add this to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use php on the header page to detect what page the user is on, and display the relevant stylesheet.

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$clean = array("/", ".php");
$page = str_replace($clean, "", $page);
echo "
<link href=css/$page.css media=screen rel=stylesheet type=text/css />";
?>
```

If you are on index.php, then this script will include index.css, main.php will include main.css, etc.

Comment: that's quite ugly way of having header. it must contain minimum php code