# Why are my background images not showing in ie8?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

Last week I finished coding this site for a music business: http://academy.young1.org.

It worked like a charm in ie10 and chrome, and I was busy showing it to everyone, but when I switched over to ie8 I suddenly realised that all my background images had disappeared.

There are other minor problems too (such as the text alignment of the top menu, the 'contact' page and the pagination on the WMU Slider Jquery plugin) but the background image issue is bugging me the most!

I am using the css: 'body { background: url("img/yourimagehere"); }' syntax.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="header">

        <div class="container_16 clearfix">
            <ul class="nav grid_16 alpha">
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Home") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="index.php" accesskey="1"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "About Us") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="about_us.php" accesskey="2"> About </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "What We Do") {echo "here"; } ?>" href="what_we_do.php" accesskey="3"> What We Do </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Enrolement") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="enrolement.php" accesskey="4"> Enrolement </a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Contact Us") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="contact.php" accesskey="5"> Contact Us </a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="http://youngacademyblog.blogspot.co.uk/" accesskey="6"> Blog </a></li>-->
            </ul>


            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="img/Logo original.gif" alt="The Young Academy"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "grid_4 alpha">

            <div class="telephone grid_4 alpha">
                <img src="img/phone_icon_white.png" alt="small telephone logo" class="align-left small" />
                <p> +44 (0)20 8866 3813 </P>
            </div>
            <div class="timezone">

                    <p><?php
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
                    mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970);
                    echo date('l, d F Y'); 
                    ?> </p>

                    <!--<form action="http://www.example.com/login.php">
                        <p>

                            <input type="text name=search" size="20+" id="search" value="Search this site"
                        </p>
                    </form>!-->



                </div>

            </div>


<ul class="secondmenu grid_6 push_3">

    <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "Musical Glossary") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="glossary.php">Musical Glossary </a></li>
    <li><a class="<?php if ($section == "FAQ") {echo "here" ; } ?>" href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>

<ul>                    
            </div> 

        <div class="container_16 clearfix">

            <div class="wmuSlider">
                <div class="wmuSliderWrapper"/>
```

etc.
and my CSS:

```
/*html5 fix*/
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body {


    background: url("../img/soft_wallpaper.png");



}

/****************
header
*****************/

.header {
    background: #212962 url("../img/header_backgrounddark.png");
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    /*z-index: 11; */


}

#logo {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
```

etc.

The easiest way to compare might be to view the site in the two browsers and click 'view source'...

I would appreciate it if anyone could help!

Regards,

Robert

Comment: No DOCTYPE defined. May be not the problem here, but...

Comment: Just so you know, it's not working on IE9 either. And I can see a duplicate of styles? index.css and style.css?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the fact that your CSS isn't complete. Some browsers can tolerate such things, but it's generally better for wider cross browser support (and to avoid odd bugs) if you're a little more verbose.

Instead of just:

```
background: url("../img/soft_wallpaper.png");
```

make it:

```
background: #ffffff url("../img/soft_wallpaper.png") no-repeat left top;
```

This tells the browser where to put the background and wither or not to repeat it. It also provides a background color fallback in the off chance that the image isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, remove those quotes because they create compatibilty issues in Safari.
As W3C says:

> Some characters appearing in an unquoted URI, such as parentheses,
>   white space characters, single quotes (') and double quotes ("), must
>   be escaped with a backslash so that the resulting URI value is a URI
>   token: '(', ')'.

So it would be better to not escape those quotes but remove them from out URL.

Second thing, add 2 more properties:

`background-repeat: no-repeat;`
`background-position: left top;`

These two properties will tell it to not repeat the image if it's size is shorter than its container and the `background-position` takes 2 values normally, **horizontal-alignment** and **vertical-alignment** and so the image will be displayed form the top-left corner of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is loading fine but in IE body background is not visible because it's covered by the dark blue `.header` div. This happens because IE is thrown into Quirks mode by missing Doctype declaration and markup errors. You can see the background image if you load your site on a bigger screen or zoom out.

In Quirks mode the content of `.wmuSlider` is forcing `.header` to expand and `.header`'s height is ignored. Fix your markup and the issue will go away. You can see that if you swith IE Document Mode to Standards using Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks - this answer is the closest one.

Comment: It's actually a CSS problem - I was including some CSS inline styles and stylesheets in the <body> instead of in the <head> sections of the page. I have now altered this, but I still have a question relating to PHP - how does one include custom inline styles and individual stylesheets (for a single page) when including a PHP 'header' file? Is it possible to have <head> sections in both the PHP 'header' file and the html document that includes it?

Comment: Here's one option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503688/using-includes-and-stylesheets-for-a-specific-page and here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347550/how-to-link-different-style-sheets-for-different-php-include-files